# iOS PushNotification using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, ios11.4

I am implementing Pushnotification on my project.I have Connected my project to firebase and than if I push notification from firebase Cloud messaging than notification properly coming in my Real-Devices. but if I test on my real-Device to Real-Device notification than Notification is not Coming. 
I dont know how to present Push Notification.

Please any one help me.

Comment: what are using to send notification from one device to another?

Comment: I am giving you a scenario, Just like a boss of company  Given a task to his Employee than Employee geting a notification from Boss when Employee using the App and when Employee not Using App (App is in Background as well as in Forground).

Comment: I'm asking you about the backend how are you using the backend to send notification

Comment: Integrated FCM with PHP Script.

Comment: that is the point where you need to verify. what are you using device token or topic?

Comment: I am Using Device Token.

Comment: this thing can be debugged at server end. try to get token and try manual thing also at server end

Comment: please give me the Method which will Catch notification in AppDelegate Class when app is in Forground or Background.

Comment: there is single method **didReceiveRemoteNotification**

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {
        print("User Info = ",userInfo)
    }

Comment: in userInfo automatically the notification Messages like(Title,Message, Body,) will be there which is send by server.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description I can understand that the issue might be from backend. Please confirm with him 2 things

- Server key he added is correct from your project in firebase console.
- Are you setting him correct notification token.
- The notification code of firebase token added is correct.

I have shared some php push notification sending link you can show to backend. But from app side things required are 
 - Push notification enable from capabilities.
 - certification which is uploaded to firebase is proper.
 - firebase token is generating or not

Comment: Yeah, It was a problem on Server Side / Backend. now it's working. I have resolved everything.